# How can i import a lib in global so i can access it in an imported js file?

Tags: javascript, import, lib

*Why i think that put my lib in global and access it in different files is a valid choice :
First i have one js file, but my file was getting bigger so i just separate it in two, and now i access to my second file functions with an export of functions.
So why do i have to import one time the lib when im on a single file, but multiple times when i use multiple files*

**What i want to do**

I have an error when i try to use a lib in JavaScript.

For the example i will use 'lib' instead of a real library from js

This is my files

**app.js**

```
import lib from 'lib'

console.log(lib)
```

This is working, but when i add

**app.js**

```
import lib from 'lib'
import my_file from './file_path.js'
```

**file_path.js**

```
console.log(lib)
```

This is not working and i have to import my lib in the new file like

**file_path.js**

```
import lib from 'lib'
console.log(lib)
```

***I GET THIS ERROR***

*Uncaught ReferenceError: lib is not defined*

But i don't want to duplicate my import, How can i do it ?  thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of the actual file path?  You need it to be a relative path (starts with './')

Comment: Is there any error in the console?

Comment: @DavinTryon i use ./, not finding the path is not my issue

Comment: @Reger i get : Uncaught ReferenceError: lib is not defined

Comment: I guess you're trying to access `lib` inside `file_path.js`and it is not defined there? You should import `lib` there too, isn't it?

Comment: @Reger This is exactly waht i want to avoid, i know that it is working if i import again the lib. But this will be a duplication of import. I try to find a way to import a lib in global so i can access it in exported js files. Maybe i found a solution with window.lib = require('lib'). But this isnt working right now

Comment: The question is why you wan't to do that? I mean, AFAIK what you're doing it's an absolutely valid choice and the best one, as it clearly specifies the dependency. Going global normally isn't a good option

Comment: @Reger i added an explaination (in my global post on top) of why i think its a good idea to put the lib in global

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/!\ You have to be in a node application to use this method /!\

I also find an alternative of the window and import

We can use require like that:

```
window.lib = require('lib');
```

Now we just have one line instead of 2
This is the best solution i found so far, don't know if we can do better, let me know

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution who work with window

you just have to add your lib in a window variable like that:

**app.js**

```
import lib from 'lib';
window.lib = lib;

import my_file from './file_path.js'
```

And now you can use your lib in "my_file" without importing it again

*PS: thanks to people who help me resolving my issue :)*

Comment: I didn't know that it could work. Bear in mind that `window` is the global object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object.